# Run Ansys APDL Model in a loop with changing a variable in the input file

Tags: for-loop, ansys

I have an APDL model. In the input.dat file I want to modify a variable (time) and then run the model again and get the output file (containing calculation results).
I want to automize the process so that I have a for loop in which at every iteration the time variable changes and the model will be executed.

I thought about doing it in python but I couldn't.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it all inside APDL with something like:

```
nTime = 5
*dim,timesArr,array,nTime
timesArr(1) = 1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0
*do,i,1,nTime  !loop over number of time variables
  /MKDIR,D:\temp\model_%i%  ! D:\temp must exist
  /CWD,D:\temp\model_%i%    ! Change working directory 
  !---------------------------------------! 
  !       your input file goes here
  !---------------------------------------! 
  /solu ! Set time variable in /solu
  time,timesArr(i)
  !---------------------------------------! 
  !   boundaries and postprocessing here
  !---------------------------------------! 
save,model_%i%,db
*enddo
```